# Modifying an existing regex to find a pattern until "Index=0"

Tags: regex

I have an existing regex that I need to modify.

The current regex is: `{(\bVar Name=)\w+\b[^{}]*}` which works on patterns as `"{Var Name=New Variable Selection List}"` and finds the pattern: "New Variable Selection List".

It also works on more complex strings where there are multiple patterns one inside another.

Now, I need to modify the string to: "{Var Name=New Variable Selection List Index=current}" where the "Index=current" part can be letters and numbers with '=' sign inside it.

In this string, I still need to find only the pattern "New Variable Selection List", but the regex still needs to find if there are multiple occurs as it does now.

Also, I need to create another regex to find only the "Index=current" part.

Comment: What is the tool or language? What is the expected outcome of `{Var Name=New Variable Selection List Index=current a=1}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Provided `Index=current` is always the last string in the sequence and it doesn't contain any spaces (otherwise it would be impossible to distinguish beginning of the index from the end of the previous entry), you can read the string with [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/Z8GvAD/1):

```
/(?<entry>(?<key>[\w ]+)=(?<value>[\w ]+)) (?=[\w=]+)(?<index>[\w=]+)/gm
```

Breaking down it into parts:

1. `(?<entry>(?<key>[\w ]+)=(?<value>[\w ]+))` - reads the the first pair of values. `entry` capture group contains both key and value: `Var Name=New Variable Selection List`
2. `(?<key>[\w ]+)` - looks for the first part of the entry: `Var Name`
3. `(?<value>[\w ]+)` - looks for the second part of the entry: `New Variable Selection List`
4. `(?=[\w=]+)` - a space and a lookahead that prevents the `<entry>` capture group to extend up to the `index` part
5. `(?<index>[\w=]+)` - looks for the index part: `Index=current`

#### Edit:

If `Index=current` part is optional, you can extend regex like [this](https://regex101.com/r/XgJakg/1):

```
/(?(DEFINE)(?'inseq'([\w]+=[\w]+)))(?<entry>(?<key>[\w ]+)=(?<value>[\w ]+))(?=(?: (?P>inseq)|}))\s?(?<index>(?P>inseq))?/gm
```

Unlike previous version it has the following additions:

1. `(?(DEFINE)(?'inseq'([\w]+=[\w]+)))` - predefined patter to match index part (to reuse it in both lookahead and corresponding capture group)
2. `\s?(?<index>(?P>inseq))?` - the final capture group (and space) are now optional
3. `(?=(?: (?P>inseq)|}))` - the lookahead now checks for closing curly bracket OR the index pattern

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. May you explain a bit about the regex so I would better understand it?

Comment: @TomSendrovich sure. Added each part explained. Should you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask